# Java Override Method In Instantiated Object Information Transfer

Tags: java, overriding, listener, instantiation

Please note: I am new in this subject.

Suppose I have a class Event.

```
public class Event {
    //constructors, etc.

    public void pathFollowed(int location) {
        //this method could be called at any time
    }
}
```

And a class called EventManager.

```
public class EventManager {
    private int managerLocation;
    private ArrayList<Event> events;
    public EventManager() {
        events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    }
    public void addEvent(Event e) {
        //THIS IS THE AREA OF INTEREST
        events.add(e);
    }
}
```

In the "area of interest" comment, is there any way of setting the value of managerLocation whenever the Event e calls upon pathFollowed(int location). My goal is that when any of the Events in the events arraylist calls pathFollowed(int location) that managerLocation would be set to "location" ("location" referring to the input in the pathfollowed method).

I was originally thinking of over-riding the pathFollowed method, but then I realized this can't be done because by the time the event gets to the addEvent method, it is already instantiated and can't be changed in this manner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some kind of listener pattern?

```
public class Event {
    private List<PathListener> pls; //Or just one if you know you'll only need one
    //constructors, etc.

    public void pathFollowed(int location) {
        //this method could be called at any time
        for(PathListener pl : pls)
            pl.notifyLocation(location);
    }

    public addPathListener(PathListener pl) {
        pls.add(pl);
    }
}
```

EventManager:

```
public class EventManager implements PathListener {
    private int managerLocation;
    private ArrayList<Event> events;
    public EventManager() {
        events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    }
    public void addEvent(Event e) {
        e.addPathListener(this);
        events.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public notifyLocation(int location) { //Of the PathListener interface
        managerLocation = location;
    }
}
```

This is just a kind-of-generic example, because I don't know what your purpose is, but maybe it will get you thinking.